# Separator within an EnumProperty

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I'm trying to insert an separator to an EnumProperty like used in the Operator object.select_by_type. This is the Property used by this Operator (blender-2.77a.tar/blender-2.77a/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_object.c - it's written in C):

```
EnumPropertyItem rna_enum_object_type_items[] = {
    {OB_MESH, "MESH", 0, "Mesh", ""},
    OBTYPE_CU_CURVE,
    OBTYPE_CU_SURF,
    {OB_MBALL, "META", 0, "Meta", ""},
    OBTYPE_CU_FONT,
    {0, "", 0, NULL, NULL},
    {OB_ARMATURE, "ARMATURE", 0, "Armature", ""},
    {OB_LATTICE, "LATTICE", 0, "Lattice", ""},
    {OB_EMPTY, "EMPTY", 0, "Empty", ""},
    {0, "", 0, NULL, NULL},
    {OB_CAMERA, "CAMERA", 0, "Camera", ""},
    {OB_LAMP, "LAMP", 0, "Lamp", ""},
    {OB_SPEAKER, "SPEAKER", 0, "Speaker", ""},
    {0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL}
};
```

The line {0, "", 0, NULL, NULL} creates a seperator (In Python the tupel is sorted different from the C-one). In Python I can't use a tupel like ("", None, None) within the item-set and a tupel like ("", "", "") creates a new column (described here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?409613-How-to-create-columns-in-operator_menu_enum-SOLVED).

How can I add a seperator to an EnumProperty in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: I expect the c-code that generates the menu from that list will add a separator if the value is 0. I don't think we have a way to add a separator through an enum in python, so we have to create a custom menu instead of using `prop_menu_enum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for 2.9](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty):

> When an item only contains 4 items they define `(identifier, name, description, number)`.
> **Separators may be added using None instead of a tuple.** For dynamic values a callback can be passed which returns a list in the same format as the static list.

This is conspicuously [absent in the documentation for 2.79](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty), so there may not have been an easy way to do it in Python when this question was asked. But for newer versions, you can just use a straight `None` instead of a tuple.

---

Indeed, it was added in 2019: [T68260](https://developer.blender.org/T68260).